# Meteor: which first html file will iron-routing load

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm creating a Meteor application. When first creating application, Meteor has put this sample code in `hello.html`

```
<head>
  <title>hello</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  Hello World Template
</template>
```

I install `Iron-Router` package. then here is my `lib/Router.js` file:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
    this.render('post_template');
});
```

And here is my `client/templates/posts/post_template.html`

```
<template name="post_template">
   Example Template
</template>
```

I don't know why when I run this application. The result is:

```
HelloWorld Template
Example Template
```

In other word, which part of Meteor's configuration that load `hello.html` as default page, and then append all other templates in routing inside ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IR will append to the `<body>` if it exists (and otherwise add one for you) so it's recommended that you remove the entire `<body>` tag.

You are actually safe to remove the `hello.html` entirely (since you also don't need the `hello` template). If you want to keep the `head` tag, you could just modify the file to look like:

```html
<head>
  <title>hello</title>
</head>
```

---

To understand why `hello.html` is being included, see the [Structuring your application](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp) section of your docs:

> HTML files in a Meteor application are treated quite a bit differently from a server-side framework. Meteor scans all the HTML files in your directory for three top-level elements: `<head>`, `<body>`, and `<template>`. The head and body sections are separately concatenated into a single head and body, which are transmitted to the client on initial page load.

So all of your html files are always included. If you don't want to include them, you need to remove them from your app.

Comment: yes. i understand that `hello.html` loads `hello template`. the thing I don't know is: why `iron-router` loadsv `hello.html`. I don't see `hello.html` is defined anywhere else in any configuration files. so how does it happen when I create "other.html" and want iron-router point to this. thanks :)

Comment: ah. i understand. and I have tested by add "other.html" with same code as "hello.html" and I received: "helloworld template helloworld template second template" Does this mean: in meteor app, we should only have one file that has full <head></head> and <body></body> ? thanks :)

Comment: Yes that's correct. And if you are using IR, you don't even need the `body` - instead you'd use layouts to achieve a common look+feel template between routes.

Answer (score 3):

In this case the very first Meteor loads is the

```
<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

  {{> hello}}
</body>
```

Since you are calling there the hello template, thats the first you get on the screen.

I reccomend on this case use the `layout` template and remove the `<body>` tag

So **first** declare the route.

```
Router.configure({
 layoutTemplate:'layout'
})
```

delete the `<body>` and `<head>` tags and place this `layout template` instead.

```
<template name="layout">
 <navbar>
 <!-- This stuff will be available on all routes since you are declaring on the layout template -->
 </navbar>
   {{> yield}} <!-- this yield helper will render the post_template or any other -->
</template>
```

For example

If you have this 2 routes.

```
Router.route('/', function () {
    this.render('post_template');
});
Router.route('/example', function () {
    this.render('example');
});
```

What happened here, when you go through the `/` route, iron router will render the 'post_template' html into the layout template, and when you navigate to `/example`, iron router will remove the post_Template html and render the content inside `/example` template, if you want to have the same content on all pages, declare it on the `<layout>` template i.e `footers`,`navbars`, etc

The layout template its like the "master" template here.

Comment: yes. i understand that `hello.html` loads `hello template`. the thing I don't know is: why `iron-router` load `hello.html`. I don't see `hello.html` is defined anywhere else in any configuration files. So how can I do if I want Iron-Router loads "second.html" rather than "hello.html" thanks :)

Comment: Look Iron:router is for routes so if you type /hello you don't will get anything, but since you are calling it `{{> hello}}` meteor will load it, these are 2 separated things, the reason you are getting the hello template its because you are "calling" it on the `<body>` tag,

Comment: as I have editted in my first comment. it means: why iron-router loads my "hello.html". how could I do if I want to load "another_file.html" ?